# OpenVPN DNS resolution not working

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, vpn, openvpn

I'm currently trying to get a simple OpenVPN setup working and I'm almost there, except for a DNS (or routing) issue I seem to be having.

The client connects to the server just fine, and I can ping both the server (10.8.0.1) and internet IPs (8.8.8.8).  The issue comes when I try to resolve any domain names.  Here's what happens when the VPN connection is up:

```
[test@localhost etc]$ dig www.google.ca

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> www.google.ca
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
[test@localhost etc]$ dig @<client network DNS server> www.google.ca

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> @<client network DNS server> www.google.ca
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
[test@localhost etc]$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.ca

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.google.ca
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6453
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.ca.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.ca.      299 IN  A   172.217.1.3

;; Query time: 32 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8
```

As far as I know I'm pushing DNS to my client from my server:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

And I've also established routes to the client:

```
client-config-dir ccd
route <client subnet IP> 255.255.255.0
```

And in my client file:

```
iroute <client subnet IP> 255.255.255.0
```

My iptables rules on the server:

```
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s <client subnet IP>/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

I've enabled ip forwarding in sysctl.  Not really sure where to look from here, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you've [resolved this problem](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=21678). Just repeat it here for others. These options:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

will not work on Linux client without appropriate `--up` script. So it's necessary to add

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

to the client settings. And I think that specified script is something like [this one](https://github.com/masterkorp/openvpn-update-resolv-conf) (UPD: in my Kubuntu something similar has been installed on installing openvpn itself)

Comment: please note that this might not be enough on systemd-resolved running OS.